# How could I give jQuery plugin multiple pre-set default options?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Say, I have a jquery plugin with default options that can be overridden just like any plugin.

What I want to do is add multiple default options that can be called via the options or somewhere in the plugin "trigger". 
Question is.. How?

Jsfiddle that sort of explains it further:
http://jsfiddle.net/A7LMc/

<sub>How this plugin works is completely irrelevant to the question.</sub>

---

---

Essentially something like this:

```
    if ( option == 'b' ) { 
         var defaults = {
            width: '260',
            height: '120'
        }; 
    }
    else {
        var defaults = {
            width: '60',
            height: '10'
        };
    }
```

and then call it in the options something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.boxes').b({
    option: 'b',
    width: '500'
    });
}); 
</script>
```

---

---

**To further elaborate:**

This works but is not what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/A7LMc/1/ ( in the js  )

========

This doesn't work and is more or less what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/A7LMc/2/ (in the html  )

..the reason why I said "more or less" is because.. well, it doesn't work and I don't really care how I can call it forth as long as it is in the plugin trigger code that is inside `<script>` tags and is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved to the plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/A7LMc/3/

```
    if ( options.option == 'b' ) {
         var defaults = {
            width: '260',
            height: '120'
        };
    }
    else {
        var defaults = {
            width: '60',
            height: '10'
        };
    }
```

And then:

```
$('.boxes').b({
option: "b",
width: '500'
});
```

---

```
var optiondefault = "width:500";
var optiona = { width: 260, height: 120, optiondefault  }
var optionb = { width: 60, height: 10, optiondefault }

$('.boxes').b({optiona});
```

Otherwise why not do it inside the plugin?

Or you could do it as an array like this....

```
var options = {
                a:{ width: '100', height:'100' },
                b: { width: '100', height:'100' }
            };

$('.boxes').b({options["a"]});
```

Comment: I need to call the specific option from the plugin trigger code. Meaning the code that triggers the plugin ( inside the <script> tags )

Comment: Added some more clarification in the bottom of the question.

Comment: Alright, I will have to test this out.. ..because I was starting to dive deeper into desperation thinking it isn't doable because nothing seemed work the way I wanted, But this does seem to do exactly what I wanted and how I originally thought it should work.

Comment: Yea, it does seem to work. I'm just in a state of shock because its so simple and about exactly how I visioned it to work like.. and I've been trying to do this since like last tuesday :D I'll just go and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer your comment not your question,

```
   obj =  {
       a : {
          width: '100',
          height: '100'
       },
       b : {
          width: '200',
          height: '200'
       },
    }
//obj.a.width >>>> 100
//obj.b.width >>>> 200
```

OR

```
obj = {
  [
     { width: '100', height:'100' },
     { width: '200', height:'200' },
  ]
}

// obj.[0].width >>> 100
// obj.[1].width >>> 200
```

as for your question jquery already does that for you, to override default options with the options provided on the callback,

if you want multiple options to override it again, it's silly, coz who would want to override something they have override already on the same call back ...

**UPDATES**

here is your last option

```
obj = {
    options : {
         option_a : {width: '',height:''},
         option_b : {width: '',height:''}
    },
    use_option: 'b'
}

$('.boxes').b(obj);
```

this way you can control it within your widget/extended plugin

Comment: I dont want to override the default options with another set of default options or anything like that. I want to have sets of default options that can be called to be active from the trigger code ( meaning that one set of options would be active at a time ). As an addition to that I would like to be override those just like  I normally would.. The reason why I mentioned that is because I didn't want a solution that doesn't let me do that.

Comment: Added some more clarification in the bottom of the question.

Comment: The only way I can see this working, is by using, a global variable, and assign it before the `$('.boxes').b({...});` or assign it to put options in an object and as a sibling you'd have which option to use.... look the edited answer....